# Resources for stories involving antiquated computers

Tags: computers, worldbuilding-resources

I am looking for resources - websites, books, etc... - that have information on antiquated computers. Specifically those from around 1975 onwards.
Maybe with clock speeds of about 5MHz+. I don't need specific information - something like a history would be ideal. I have some knowledge of processor architecture and assembly programming, so I would be comfortable reading somewhat technical stuff.
I'm mostly interested in microcomputers, but I'm looking for inspiration, so don't let that limit you.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What kinds of computers? Mainframes, minis, microcomputers? 5MHz clock speed is actually pretty high for 1975.

Comment: I edited my question. The 5MHz figure is based on the Intel 8086, which came out in 1978, so you're right that it's pretty high :-)

Comment: which kind of information, how they look like, how they where produced, how they work or ...?

Comment: Like I said, a history would be ideal. What machines where developed when, and by who. How well they sold, how that was influenced by their capabilities, and so on.

Comment: Leaning toward off topic. Look at old issues of Byte magazine, Scientific American, IEEE Spectrum, ACM Communications. Biographies of the founders of Intel may lead to more technical references.

Comment: I might have missed something, but... how is that about worldbuilding ?

Comment: You can read old Byte issues at the InternetArchive.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin does WB have to be an invention, or do we cover researching existing settings (technology, society, culture) for writing?  I added the [tag:worldbuilding-resources] tag, so it should be ok-enough and get pointers, not actual details.

Comment: @JDługosz See http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3911/resolving-the-real-world-problem In any case, a resource on the history of computer can hardly be categorised as worldbuilding. Besides, wikipedia have lengthy information about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For information on the history of computers you can visit:

- [OldComputers.net](http://oldcomputers.net/)
- [Computer History Museum](http://www.computerhistory.org/)
- [History of Computers: A Brief Timeline](http://www.livescience.com/20718-computer-history.html) at livescience.com
- [A Brief History of Computing - Complete Timeline](http://trillian.randomstuff.org.uk/~stephen/history/timeline.html) by Stephen White
- [History of computing hardware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_computing_hardware) at Wikipedia.org

Note: posted as comunity wiki, please edit and add.

Answer (score 0):

The [Computer History Museum](http://www.computerhistory.org/) has all sorts of stuff that you're looking for.

Comment: Why not add that to the community wiki answer?